# Uploaded app with new Bundle Id, doesn't show on the dashboard

Tags: ios, google-fabric

I have uploaded a new ios binary of my app with a new bundle ID.

I am waiting for quite some time for it to show on my dashboard, but it's not showing.

Are there any steps that can be done to make this faster? or just to be sure the binary is there?

Comment: By "uploaded a new iOS binary" do you mean you did a new distribution using Fabric Beta? If so, did you both build and run your app with the new bundle ID before uploading to Beta?

Comment: I have solved this issue with Fabric's support. Thank you for your help. The new bundle ID was not showing up in the dashboard. But I had builded it to device and simulator and uploaded an IPA to their servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build and run the app in your simulator with the Fabric.with statement, the run script build phase, and the info.plist entries your app will then appear on the dashboard. After that you'll be able to use the Beta distribution product of Fabric.

Thanks!